# Extract Data from chatroom messages using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, extract, text-extraction, information-extraction

Hello I am looking to extract data from messages of a chatroom. Each message has the same class but a unique "messageId=#" with the bigger numbers being the most recent. within each message I am trying to extract 3 classes and their contents. I am then trying to sort by the message id #(small to big) and the three extracted contents(4 colomns) into an excel/spreadsheet.

Currently using selenium

tried driver.find_element. which sent me back an error